# How to access elements from passed generic arraylist

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm having problems with figuring out how generics method in java works when you pass arraylist.

So basically I have few DTOs like: TypeAwesome, TypeGreat, TypeNotSoGreat

These DTOs read from a text file(each from their own) and I have getters that I would like to use.

DTO represents each row in a csv file and I save those DTO objects into ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<TypeAwesome> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < lineCount; i++) {
    typeAwesome = new TypeAwesome();
    ...
    list.add(typeAwesome); 
}
return fileHelper.checkFinalResult(list);
```

So as you can see I am passing that list.

My goal is to whatever the Type of list I send in I want to get that List attributes and getters.

Basically I get errors like this:

- Cannot resolve method 'get' in T
- Cannot resolve method 'size' in T
- Cannot resolve method 'get' in T
- foreach not applicable to type T

  ```
  public <T extends Base> String checkFinalResult(List<T> list) {
      String finalStatus = "FAIL";
      List<String> statuses = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
          System.out.println(list.get(i).getRezultat());
          String status = list.get(i).getRezultat().equalsIgnoreCase("OK") ? "PASS" : "FAIL";
          statuses.add(status);
          // returns last result - to determine if whole test failed or not
          if (i == list.size() - 1) {
              if (list.get(i).getRezultat().equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                  finalStatus = "PASS";
              }
          }
      }
      System.out.println("STATUSES: " + statuses);
      int index = 0;
      for (T item : list) {
          // get status
          item.status = statuses.get(index);
          System.out.println("ITEM STATUS " + item.status);
          index++;
      }
      return finalStatus;
  }
  ```

How can I pass ArrayList of some type so that get method works on that list, is there another way to achieve what I want to achieve ?

EDIT: I've made necessary fix and implemented base class like stated in comments:
Base class:

```
public class Base {
    public String rezultat;
    public String status;
    public String getRezultat() {
        return rezultat;
    }
}
```

I am now getting error at, above:

```
return fileHelper.checkFinalResult(list);
```

Required type:
List

Provided:
List

reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that TypeAwesome conforms to Base

What does this mean, do I have to create that instance so that TypeAwesome conforms to Base?

Comment: IMHO the method signature has to be `public <T> String checkFinalResult(List<T> list, Class<T> type) {...}`

Comment: @spa what is the point of that `type` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you really want is for the List to contain the generic type. So your method signature should be:

```
public <T> checkFinalResults(List<T> list) {...}
```

That will get you passed your current errors but you are trying to invoke the `getRezultat()` method on the elements of the List.  If each of your DTOs extends a common base class or implements a common interface, then you can access the methods of that type by specifying this in the generic definition.  e.g.

```
public <T extends HasRezultat> checkFinalResults(List<T> list) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and thanks for the additional information! I will come back and post my solution when I finish.

Comment: Hi vsfDawg, do you mind helping me with one more bit I posted on edit.